# whenever i choose POS tagger in my .net code. it shows me unsupported major.minor error.. why?

Tags: netbeans

The `complete error` is something like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/MaxentTagger: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To better help others answer your question, please provide the code where you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve it, Easiest way **is to download and update latest version of JRE** in the system which is running java code.